# Compare Two Different Fields In Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requirement in which I have two main fields Amount CR and Amount DR.
Now the  requirement is that this both amounts have different values like Trx Number, Bank Name ETC but have a common Reference Number.
There is only one record for every Refrence Number with a CR Amount, DR Amount respectivly.

For detaila see the table below:

| Transaction Number | Bank Name | Reference Number | CR Amount | DR Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XYZ | 1234 | 1000 |  |
| 2 | ABC | 1234 |  | 1000 |
| 3 | DEF | 1111 |  | 1000 |
| 4 | TEST | 1111 | 2300 |  |

So basically I want to compare CR and DR Amount based on the Reference Number. In the example  Reference Number 1234 is ok and Reference Number 1111 should be listed.

How can I achieve this by an Oracle query?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what it is that you want to return.  Do you want to return 2 rows, one per reference number, which contains both the CR and DR amount?  Do you want to return rows 1 & 2 because they match?  3 & 4 because they don't match?  Something else?  Is there always exactly 1 CR and 1 DR amount per reference number?  Or could you CR one bank and DR two banks (or vice versa)?

Comment: I want to show only those rows for whom cr and dr amount is not same but reference number is same here in example reference number 1111 has different cr and dr amount so i want to show both transactions 3 & 4 but i am not sure how to achieve that. And yes there is only one cr and dr amount for reference number but have different transaction number for that. And for bank it may same bank or may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two analytical aggregated functions calculating the sum of `CR`and `DB` per the `reference_number` and compare them

```
case when
sum(cr_amount) over (partition by reference_number) =
sum(dr_amount) over (partition by reference_number) then 'Y' else 'N' end is_equ
```

This identifies the rows with `reference_number` where the sum is *not equal*.

In an additional query simple filter only the rows where the *not equal* sum.

```
with test as (
select a.*,
case when 
sum(cr_amount) over (partition by reference_number) =
sum(dr_amount) over (partition by reference_number) then 'Y' else 'N' end is_equ
from tab a)
select 
  TRANSACTION_NUMBER, BANK_NAME, REFERENCE_NUMBER, CR_AMOUNT, DR_AMOUNT
from test 
where is_equ = 'N'

TRANSACTION_NUMBER BANK REFERENCE_NUMBER  CR_AMOUNT  DR_AMOUNT
------------------ ---- ---------------- ---------- ----------
                 3 DEF              1111                  1000
                 4 TEST             1111       2300
```

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that there is exactly one record with dr and one with cr amount you can make a self join over the reference number.
The 2 Trransactions for a Reference Number will be listed in one row:

```
select * from table t1 
 inner join table t2 on t1.referencenumber = t2.referencenumber 
                   and t1.cr_amount is not null
                   and t2.dr_amount is not null
where t1.cr_amount <> t2.dr_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate and use a `case` expression:

```
select reference_number,
       sum(cr_amount), sum(db_amount),
       (case when sum(cr_amount) = sum(db_amount)
             then 'same' else 'different'
        end)
from t
group by reference_number;
```